# Velocity: Is a any way to check if variable is defined

Tags: variables, velocity, template-engine

I want to include one template `nested` into others `cont1`, `cont2`, `cont3`. 
And nested template should be hide one specific control for cont1 only.
Before inclusion into `cont1` I would like to assign value to some flag variable `$hideMyControl`.

And inside nested template I would like to check if `$hideMyControl` is assigned value.

How to perform such check?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can do this using

```
  #if($!{$articleLeader})
      // Perform your operation or the template part you want to show.
  #end
```

For more info, see the 'formal reference' section of the [Apache Velocity Reference Manual](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/user-guide.html#References).

Comment: There's no point to using formal and silent notation in an #if, which you didn't quite get right anyway.  Just do #if( $article ) ## perform op here #end

Comment: So what about checking if it's NOT defined?

Comment: This answer users [Quiet Reference Notation](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/2.0/user-guide.html#quiet-reference-notation) that may lead to exception being thrown on undefined reference in [Strict Reference Mode](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/2.0/user-guide.html#strict-reference-mode). See [VELOCITY-739](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/VELOCITY-739).

Answer (score 37):

```
#if($hideMyControl)
    // your code
#end
```

If `$hideMyControl` is defined, your code will execute

Answer (score 11):

```
#if($!{hideMyControl} != "")
## do something if $hideMyControl is defined
#end
```

This works for me in AWS API Gateway Body Mapping Templates. Please refer to [Quiet Reference Notation](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/user-guide.html#quiet-reference-notation) in Velocity User Guide for more information.

Comment: Only one that worked for me in AWS API Gateway Body Mapping Templates.

Answer (score 1):

I was using

```
#if ($hideMyControl) 
    //do something 
#end
```

since a few months ago,
however today its not working anymore.

I came here to find help, and noticed a new way of writing it :

```
#if($!{$hideMyControl})
   // do something
#end
```

this code works!

Comment: `since a few months ago, however today its not working anymore.`
Is this maybe a Velocity 2.0 migration issue? - see "method arguments are now converted as needed between all main basic Java standard types (booleans, numbers and strings)."

Comment: wow im glad i left the job that hired me to do that a few years ago, no one ever told me they migrated versions as i was coding up the EDI part of their ERP systems using that language. glad i left that company it was a shitshow lol.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs for Strict Reference Mode](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/user-guide.html#strict-reference-mode) it is possible to several constructions to check if variable is defined.

> ```
> #if ($foo)#end                  ## False
> #if ( ! $foo)#end               ## True
> #if ($foo && $foo.bar)#end      ## False and $foo.bar will not be evaluated
> #if ($foo && $foo == "bar")#end ## False and $foo == "bar" wil not be evaluated
> #if ($foo1 || $foo2)#end        ## False $foo1 and $foo2 are not defined
> ```

So this code works in my case.

```
#if( !$value )
  // Perform your operation or the template part you want to show.
#end
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if $hideMyControl is in Velocity context and IS NOT boolean 'true' value (or 'false' as well):

```
#if ($hideMyControl && $hideMyControl != true)
    ##do stuff
#end
```

Sure, if you really use your $hideMyControl variable as boolean type, you don't need second part of condition.