# Velocity is interpreting int i = 0 as boolean false

Tags: velocity

If I check var int i = 0 for existing I get wrong result:

```
#if($i)
  <output>$i</output>
#end
```

results in:

```
i not defined --> no output
i = 0         --> no output
i = 1         --> <output>1</output>
```

How can I tell velocity to consider value 0 as defined?

```
i not defined --> no output
i = 0         --> <output>0</output>
i = 1         --> <output>1</output>
```

Comment: I just had a similar problem and found out that the behavior of Velocity has changed from Version 1.7 to Version 2.3 (presumably during the major version change). In Version 1.7 0 evaluates to true, in Version 2.3 0 evaluates to false.

Comment: Appending on my last comment, this is desired behavior hat changes, this can also be seen from the Velocity documentation.

https://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.7/user-guide.html#if-elseif-else
https://velocity.apache.org/engine/2.3/user-guide.html#if-elseif-else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check with an [operator](http://people.apache.org/%7Ehenning/velocity/html/ch06.html)

```
#if($i >= 0)
  <output>$i</output>
#end
```

Comment: It does not throw an exception when $i is not defined

Comment: I would appreciate if velocity whould add a command like "exists". #ifexists($i)

Comment: @HasanTuncay see if `!` helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825636/velocity-is-a-any-way-to-check-if-variable-is-defined